# How do I generate regular expression for the following string

Tags: regex

I have requirements for the password as follows

1. at least 6 characters long.
2. Must have at least one non letter or digit character.
3. Must have at least one digit ('0'-'9').
4. Must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').

I don't know how to create a regular expression for the above string requirement.

**EDIT:** 
Here is the typical password I could use

Mhal@qat1t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which characters it can/cannot have, I made it like this:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^\da-zA-Z])\S{6,}$
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. I gave an example of password in the EDIT section.